# Swift Optional Patterns

Tags: swift

Swift optional pattern allows you to use **case let** like this:

```
var arrayOfOptional: [Int?] = [1, 2, nil, 4]

for case let number? in arrayOfOptional {
  print("\(number)")
}
```

What confuses me is the **let number?** syntax. In optional binding, the unwrapped version does not have **?**, but in case let, it does. How do you interpret this construct for it to make sense for you that number is unwrapped?

Functionally, what's the difference between the two below:

```
if let x = someOptional {
  print(x)
}
```

versus

```
if case let x? = someOptional {
  print(x)
}
```

Comment: `x?` is just a shortcut for `.Some(x)` in a pattern (as documented in [Optional Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID520)). Is your question *why* Apple chose this particular syntax? (I think it was discussed in the Apple Developer Forum whether this is  intuitive or not.)

Comment: This syntax is the opposite of optional binding, which unwraps without you specifying ?, trying to find a way to interpret this in a way that I can remember the behavior more easily.  Also, given that this is a shortcut for .Some(x), what if you do straight x without ? (e.g. if case let x) - what does that map to?

Comment: `if case let x = y {  }` is quite useless. It it always true and assigns `y` to `x`. But `if case let x as SubClass = y { }` is functionally equivalent to `if let x = y as? SubClass { }`. – Optional patterns are more general than optional binding, they can be used in switch/if/while/for statements, and the syntax is just different (and perhaps not intuitive).

Answer (score 3):

I just tested your first code, never used for pattern matching before but here is what I assume:

```
var arrayOfOptional: [Int?] = [1, 2, nil, 4]

for case let number in arrayOfOptional {
    print("\(number)")
}
// will return 3 optional ints and a nil

for case let number? in arrayOfOptional {
    print("\(number)")
}
// will return only any values that could be unwrapped
```

I assume that this is a pattern which unwraps any optional value under the hood and only proceed if it could be unwrapped and will.

```
if case let x? = someOptional {
    print(x)
}
```

`case let` is used for pattern matching like `switch x { case let ... }`. In your example it will also try to unwrap an optional value. If it's a nil it will fail

Comment: Right - and I find this pattern to be confusing, basically adding ? does the opposite of not having it (esp when comparing to optional binding). Trying to find a way to interpret this so I can remember better.

Comment: This one is also really handy (Swift 2.0): `guard instance.dynamicType is AnyClass else { /* nope it's a structure type, do something here */ }` But it's bugged atm. This one will only be true if your instance is a class otherwise it will fail. And it will ignore bridging to ObjC. Kinda nice to know.